# Почему не возникает 404-ая ошибка при обращении к несуществующей странице в постраничной навигации?

Tags: yii2

К примеру есть 5 записей, по одной на странице. Почему при обращении к 6-ой странице yii спокойно ее обрабатывает? Разве не должно вернуть ошибку хотя бы о том, что нет такой страницы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть это по вашей теме учитывая что я слышал о таком баге.
http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31874

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.